# conditionally add new xml element after specific sibling node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to add a new XML element at a specific place using the Identity Transformation and a predicate match of a child node within the context node. I can successfully add the elements however the order of the XML is important and my current xsl script is placing the new elements within the context node of my template matching statement, essentially placing the new element as an 'out of sequence' sibling node. Below is my source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
   <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
      <PmtInf>
         <CdtTrfTxInf>
            <CdtrAgt>
               <FinInstnId>
                  <Nm>Exciting Place</Nm>
               </FinInstnId>
               <BrnchId>
                  <Nm>Big Building</Nm>
                  <PstlAdr>
                     <Ctry>BR</Ctry>
                  </PstlAdr>
               </BrnchId>
            </CdtrAgt>
            <Cdtr>
               <Nm>/POP:Other</Nm>
            </Cdtr>
            <CdtrAcct>
               <Id>
                  <IBAN>123456789123456789</IBAN>
               </Id>
               <Ccy>USD</Ccy>
               <Nm>Winston Churchill</Nm>
            </CdtrAcct>
            <Tax>
               <TaxId>100</TaxId>
            </Tax>
            <RmtInf>
               <Ustrd>Test</Ustrd>
            </RmtInf>
         </CdtTrfTxInf>
      </PmtInf>
   </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

I need to add the elements "Purp/Cd" to the XML document following the "Tax" node ONLY when the "CdtAgt/BrnchId/Ctry" sibling node has a value of "BR". I have tried the following XSL script but it places the elements in the wrong location; I have attempted to adjust the predicate[] matching statement without any luck.  Here is my script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsl"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Generic identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Copy the children of the current node -->
    <xsl:template name="copy-children">
        <xsl:copy-of select="./*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*/CdtTrfTxInf[CdtrAgt/BrnchId/PstlAdr/Ctry[text() = 'BR']]">
        <xsl:copy>

            <xsl:element name="Purp" namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
                <xsl:element name="Cd" namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'P1019'"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:call-template name="copy-children"/>

        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This stylesheet produces an improperly aligned XML document in which the "Purp/Cd" nodes immediately follow the "CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf" node instead of the desired location following the "Tax" node; undesirable output below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
   <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
      <PmtInf>
         <CdtTrfTxInf>
            <Purp>
               <Cd>P1019</Cd>
            </Purp>
            <CdtrAgt>
               <FinInstnId>
                  <Nm>Exciting Place</Nm>
               </FinInstnId>
               <BrnchId>
                  <Nm>Big Building</Nm>
                  <PstlAdr>
                     <Ctry>BR</Ctry>
                  </PstlAdr>
               </BrnchId>
            </CdtrAgt>
            <Cdtr>
               <Nm>/POP:Other</Nm>
            </Cdtr>
            <CdtrAcct>
               <Id>
                  <IBAN>123456789123456789</IBAN>
               </Id>
               <Ccy>USD</Ccy>
               <Nm>Winston Churchill</Nm>
            </CdtrAcct>
            <Tax>
               <TaxId>100</TaxId>
            </Tax>
            <RmtInf>
               <Ustrd>Test</Ustrd>
            </RmtInf>
         </CdtTrfTxInf>
      </PmtInf>
   </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

I need the new nodes to be place after the "Tax" node but do not know how to produce the correct result while also using a predicate match at the context node level; I imagine this is my issue but do not know how to adjust my script.  Your suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Desired output below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03">
   <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
      <PmtInf>
         <CdtTrfTxInf>
            <CdtrAgt>
               <FinInstnId>
                  <Nm>Exciting Place</Nm>
               </FinInstnId>
               <BrnchId>
                  <Nm>Big Building</Nm>
                  <PstlAdr>
                     <Ctry>BR</Ctry>
                  </PstlAdr>
               </BrnchId>
            </CdtrAgt>
            <Cdtr>
               <Nm>/POP:Other</Nm>
            </Cdtr>
            <CdtrAcct>
               <Id>
                  <IBAN>123456789123456789</IBAN>
               </Id>
               <Ccy>USD</Ccy>
               <Nm>Winston Churchill</Nm>
            </CdtrAcct>
            <Tax>
               <TaxId>100</TaxId>
            </Tax>
            <Purp>
               <Cd>P1019</Cd>
            </Purp>
            <RmtInf>
               <Ustrd>Test</Ustrd>
            </RmtInf>
         </CdtTrfTxInf>
      </PmtInf>
   </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</Document>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to place your new node after the `Tax` element, you should change your template to match the `Tax` element....

```
 <xsl:template match="CdtTrfTxInf[CdtrAgt/BrnchId/PstlAdr/Ctry[text() = 'BR']]/Tax">
```

Then, inside this you can copy the `Tax` node exactly (using `xsl:next-match` as you are using XSLT 2.0), then create your new node after it.

Try this XSLT, which I have simplified a bit more by using a default namespace to output the new elements.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"
    xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsl"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Generic identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CdtTrfTxInf[CdtrAgt/BrnchId/PstlAdr/Ctry[text() = 'BR']]/Tax">
        <xsl:next-match />
        <Purp>
            <Cd>
                <xsl:text>P1019</xsl:text>
            </Cd>
        </Purp>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Nailed it, this works beautifully.  Always something simple.  Thank you for the help Tim.